# Error in afterProcess - Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have an issue with the Spring batch application I am working into. It is an intermittent issue (happens one day and then works fine for next few days) -

Multiple csv files are read line by line in this app and stored in database, I am getting following error on server when the batch script corresponding to the spring batch code runs:

```
2017-11-28 03:30:11,878 ERROR [com.inetpsa.eur.batchs.adyen.listeners.AdyenItemListener] - Error in afterProcess.
2017-11-28 03:30:11,881 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] - Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.batch.retry.RetryException: Non-skippable exception in recoverer while processing; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.listener.StepListenerFailedException: Error in onProcessError.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$2.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:420)
    at org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:289)
    at org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.transform(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:74)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:258)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.listener.StepListenerFailedException: Error in onProcessError.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.MulticasterBatchListener.onProcessError(MulticasterBatchListener.java:142)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$1.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.batch.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:240)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.inetpsa.eur.batch.adyen.executionstatus.AdyenBatchStatus.processErrors(AdyenBatchStatus.java:341)
    at com.inetpsa.eur.batchs.adyen.listeners.AdyenItemListener.onProcessError(AdyenItemListener.java:157)
    at com.inetpsa.eur.batchs.adyen.listeners.AdyenItemListener.onProcessError(AdyenItemListener.java:29)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeItemProcessListener.onProcessError(CompositeItemProcessListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.MulticasterBatchListener.onProcessError(MulticasterBatchListener.java:139)
    ... 16 more
```

The NullPointer is at the place where 'item' is read and this happens intermittently.

Any leads!

TIA!

Comment: Please provide the code for the  `AdyenBatchStatus`

Comment: I tried to look into the issue and the new thing is that it is not the code, it is the file and evironment which is creating the issue.

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see...